# Estrutura de repetição - 10% "todo dia"

Tags: javascript, html5

Não consigo fazer uma estrutura de repetição.

Exemplo de oque quero fazer:
Eu digito o valor inicial e digito a porcentagem que quero que ele aumente durante 30 dias.

Exemplo de valor inicial: 50.
Porcentagem que aumenta a cada dia: 10%;

1- R$55,00 (+10%)

2- R$60,50 (+10%)

3- R$66,55 (+10%)

4- ...

```
      var inicial = parseFloat(prompt("Digite o valor inicial:"));
      var porcentagem = parseFloat(prompt("Digite a porcentagem diária: \nOBS: 10% = 1.10"));

      var calc = parseFloat(inicial * porcentagem).toFixed(2);
      document.write(calc + "<br>");

      for (var i=0; i<=30; i++) {
        var fds = parseFloat(calc * porcentagem).toFixed(2);
        document.write(fds + "<br>")
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `calc` possui valor fixo durante todo o tempo do loop. Voce tem que atualizar o `calc` a cada iteracao do loop, pois se `calc` for R$5 no comeco, pra quando a porcentagem for 10%, a cada loop essa porcentagem deve ser calculada com base do valor do `calc` que tem que ser atualizado.
No codigo comentado abaixo, vamos calcular o valor de `calc` com uma funcao e mostrar o valor ja com a taxa de:

```js
function calculaValorComTaxa(valor, taxa) {
  return (valor * taxa) + valor; // para R$50 e porcentagem de 10%, retorna 55.
}

var inicial = parseFloat(prompt("Digite o valor inicial:"));
var porcentagem = parseFloat(prompt("Digite o valor inicial:")) / 100; // convertemos porcentagem para float dividindo por 100.

var calc = calculaValorComTaxa(inicial, porcentagem); // no primeiro momento, calc sera 55.

document.write(calc + "<br>"); // mostra 55.

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

  calc =  calculaValorComTaxa(calc, porcentagem); // agora para cada iteracao, calc vai ser calculado com base no valor anterior, 55, e atualizar o calc para um novo valor. 10% de 55 = 5,5 mais o valor antigo de 55 temos o novo valor de 60,5

  var fds = calc; // valor atualizado de 60,5. 
  
  document.write(fds + "<br>") // exibimos esse valor e refazemos a mesma logica e sempre atualizando o calc ate o fim do loop.

}
```

Tente fazer o teste e se resolve seu problema.

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!